# Functionality of require() in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I have a fundamental query of how the `require()` works in nodeJS application.

What does `require()` actually return ??

For example, say I wanted to use 2 third party packages : `lodash` and `request`. After installing the package, We can write the code as :

```
const _ = require('lodash')
_.uniq(Array)
```

So shall I understand that `require()` return an object here and `uniq` is a method from the object `_` ?

Now let's consider `request` package,

```
const request = require('request')
request (
{
  url: '',
  json:true
}
callback_function()
)
```

So shall I understand here that `require()` had returned a method directly - `request()`

If I use the same as below, I am encountering a type error that `req1.request is not a method`.

```
const req1 = require('request');
req1.request (
{
  url: '',
  json:true
}
callback_function()
)
```

Kindly help me in understanding this.

Comment: **1** *So shall I understand that `require()` return an object here and `uniq` is a method from the object* yes **2**. *shall I understand here that `require()` had returned a method directly - `request()`*. No. Here, `request` could've been `bottle`. It's just a variable name. But **it holds whatever was exported** through `module.exports` of the referenced package

Comment: Hi@Adelin.. Thank you for the explanation.  I've gone through the `uniq.js` and `request.js` from the installed packages. I've found the code present there as - `module.exports = uniq;` and `module.exports = Request`. And nowhere they are exporting any objects. Can you please explain why we used `_.uniq()` instead of direct `uniq()`. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` returns whatever the module defined. Sometimes, the module defines a single function:

```
exports = function request(/*...*/);
```

...and so when you import the module, that's what you get.

Sometimes, modules export objects (`exports` refers to a blank object initially when the module is loaded, and then modules add to or replace that object):

```
exports._ = {
    // ...
};
```

...and so when you import the module, *that's* what you get.

It's up to the module. It's a very simple system. More in the [Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) documentation (not to be confused with the [ECMAScript (JavaScript) Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) documentation; JavaScript's own modules work slightly differently from Node.js's).

Comment: Hi Crowder, thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I've gone through the `uniq.js` and `request.js` from the installed packages. I've found the code present there as - `module.exports = uniq;` and `module.exports = Request`. And no where they are exporting any objects. Can you please explain why we used `_.uniq()` instead of direct `uniq()`. Thank you.

Comment: @METALHEAD - You're not importing `uniq.js`, you're importing `lodash`, which aggregates the contents of the other files into a single module, which it exports as `_` (but also directly), see `lodash.js` which does this: `(freeModule.exports = _)._ = _;` (where `freeModule` is `module` in their bootstrapping, which is complex because it supports multiple module systems).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.